# List of classes and indices for my trained neural network model in keras

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, keras

I have trained the MNIST dataset using the code from https://www.kaggle.com/code/himanshuyadav95627/image-classification, and the model is working perfectly. Now I want to extract the class names and indices from the trained model. Why I need this: I am trying to produce a heatmap. The MNIST data set has handwritten images of the numbers 0 to 9. I believe the classes here will be 0 to 9.

My code:

```
jsn_model = model.to_json()# here model is my trained NN model and I am converting to json format
clasdf = pd.read_json(jsn_model) # convert it to a dataframe
print(clasdf['class_name'])
```

present output:

```
layers    Sequential
name      Sequential
Name: class_name, dtype: object
```

Expected output:

```
 Class names 0 to 9 and indices 0 to 9 or 1 to 10
```

For instance, an example class and indices for a known dataset
https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/imagenet_class_index.json
[image]

Comment: This information is not saved in the model file.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I am surprized. How do I get it?